# how to handle google street view api response

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-api

I am wanting to display a image from google street view. I am making a fetch call and getting a response but I do not know how to handle the image? Do I need to use something like FileReader? I am using react-native so not sure what is available to me. here is screenshot.

[image: scrrenshot]

Comment: Make it into a blob and then use createObjectUrl.Use that as src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Fetch API, you need to read the response correctly depending on the returned type.

The image is probably a blob, so you need to use the [blob() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob).

Your code should something like this after:

```
fetch(myRequest)
.then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
})
.then(function(image) {
// You get the image
});
```